# How to retrieve embedded objects using Hibernate OGM

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, hibernate-ogm

I have two classes, where one is an entity and the other one is an @Embeddable object:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    ...
    protected Integer id;
    @Embedded
    protected B b;
    protected String c;
}


@Embeddable
public class B {
    protected String d;
}
```

When i persist these in MongoDB, it works perfectly fine.
But when I query a tuple of A, b is null.

This is how I tried querying:

```
A a = em.find(A.class, 1);
A a = (A) em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A a").getSingleResult();
A a = (A) em.createNativeQuery(A.class, "{}").getSingleResult();
```

Can somebody tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been solved some time ago.
This should work with the latest Hibernate OGM version